# Cxf Mapper or interceptor does not have access to the original Error message

Tags: java, cxf

I have a Java rest web service using spring and cxf and I am trying to propagate error messages from my WS layer to my Grails/Groovy front end.  My frontend calls the webservice by referencing the client-spring of the webservice.

I have an exception mapper that gets called, and when making REST requests I get the error message there, but when using my front end which i assume uses proxies the Error message is not available.

I have also tried using interceptors, which get called, but calling
   message.getContent(Exception.class)
returns null.

When tracing the exception using a debugger the message seems to get lost
when the ServiceInvokerInterceptor is called.

I had this working with cxf 2.4, but the functionality was removed when we upgraded to 3.0, and now trying to bring it back, i'm not sure if i'm missing something, or if cxf has changed.

The only thing I can get the client to do properly is trigger the
ResponseExceptionMapper, but I have no way of getting the original exception from the response objet.

Here is a typical stack trace from the front end.

```
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. Stacktrace follows:
Message: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    Line | Method
->>   14 | fromResponse        in com.company.common.web.RestResponseExceptionMapper
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|      9 | fromResponse        in     ''
|    302 | checkResponse . . . in org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl
|    725 | handleResponse      in     ''
|    683 | doChainedInvocation in     ''
|    224 | invoke              in     ''
```

I have written 3 other questions related to this same issue and i've been pulling my hair trying to figure this out.

Comment: Please post the code of the ExceptionMapper of the server and the piece of your client that is invoking the Service. Are you using a ResponseExceptionMapper at client side?

Answer (score 0):

Try `ExceptionMapper` class. If you're working with REST services only then it's perfect solution.

Here's a sample

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {
    public final String exceptionMessagePrefix = "Exception at server.";

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable exception) {
        String stackTrace = getStackTrace(exception);

        ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        builder.entity(stackTrace);
        builder.header("Content-Type", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);

        return builder.build();
    }

    public String getStackTrace(Throwable ex) {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);

        ex.printStackTrace(out);//Only if you want it to output to console

        stringWriter.close();
        out.close();

        return stringWriter.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried using ExceptionMappers.  If I make a postman request to the Rest service, I get the actual error instead of the generic 500 error.  However the UI does not seem to get the error, The mapper is hit, but for some reason since i'm using cxf as a client as well. (My ui references my client spring file, of the back end WS) The error seems to disapear

Comment: I should rephrase, I am using exception mappers, however when accessing my WS via a axrs client-spring context, even though the exception is being hit, I still do not see it (just the generic 500 error)